# dotnet core webapi, docker and azure. Performance issues during first api call

Tags: azure, .net-core

We have a dotnet core 3.0 solution running in a docker image running on Azure. For now, we haven't set it up in a k8s cluster. Our app service plan is PremiumV2, which basically means that we're running on dedicated hardware and not sharing our resources with anyone else.

We have a simple api-call to get the executing user based on the JWT. This validates the JWT, gets the users mail from the claims and queries cosmos to get more information about the user. When the request is sent from Postman the first time, it takes roughly `320 ms`, however the subsequential requests takes around `50 ms`. If we're waiting, lets say 10 minutes more or less, the requests is back at around `300 ms` and again the subsequential requests takes around `50 ms`. This indicates that the behavior is re-producable. Its worth mentioning that its not only this call that we see this behavior, but every "first" requests to our api takes more time than the other following.

Looking into application insights, apparently cosmos is not the bottleneck here. We've also configured the app service to be `"always on"`

Any ideas on how we can trace down this issue? Has anyone else experienced the same behavior? Is there any settings or configuration we should look at in Azure?

Comment: what kind of docker image is it? Linux or Windows based? I've not seen this behavior with always on enabled while using a linux based docker image. So it probably has to do with IIS if you're using a windows based image.

Comment: We're running a Linux based docker image

Comment: do you have application map setup? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map

Comment: Yes, we have. But I cannot find any dependencies to our solution take would affect the performance. Is there something strange in Kestrel that happens? It seems to me that even if no third-party services are involved this behavior is re-produceable. I mean, even if we have a simple HTTP-GET just to return a hard-coded value, we can see this behavior